# Variable not declared error in a Maze Game

Tags: windows, vb.net, soundplayer

The maze game I have developed via a tutorial I found by research is doing well. Step by step I have been debugging this application for Windows using VB in Visual Studio 2012. I was told by the tutorial to use the following code:

```
Private Sub MoveToStart()
    startSoundPlayer.Play()
    Dim startingPoint = Panel1.Location
    startingPoint.Offset(10, 10)
    Cursor.Position = PointToScreen(startingPoint)
End Sub
```

On the line `startSound.Play()` Visual Basic gives me an error message saying: **Error Correction Options**. So I click on this and it tells me:

> 'startSoundPlayer' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its security level.

What do I do to fix this?

Comment: You declare it. I don't know what type it is, but it should be something like 'Dim startSoundPlayer as New [the type]'.

Comment: Can you post more of your code?  Where is startSoundPlayer declared?

Comment: Can you please post a link to the tutorial you're reading?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492141.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Declare:

```
Private startSoundPlayer = New System.Media.SoundPlayer("C:\Windows\Media\chord.wav")
```

As the tutorial says. In the same Class that the `MoveToStart` Method. If still fails, declare `startSoundPlayer` as `Public` instead of `Private`.

Comment: I'll test this with Public

Comment: Public startSoundPlayer = New System.Media.SoundPlayer("C:\Windows\Media\chord.wav")
    Dim finishSoundPlayer As Object

Comment: The application closes without the popup message :(

Comment: At least you solved your problem with the `startSoundPlayer` error